# SUM(DISTINCT(column)) gives wrong results in certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This query

```
SELECT u.username, 
SUM(p.likes) AS likePoints1, 
SUM(p2.likes)*2 AS likePoints2 
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT recommendedByUserId as rid, id as ruid from users WHERE created >= DATE('2013-09-16') AND created <= DATE('2013-09-30')) AS r ON r.rid = u.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created >= DATE('2013-09-16') AND created <= DATE('2013-09-30')) AS p ON p.author_id = ruid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created >= DATE('2013-09-16') AND created <= DATE('2013-09-30')) AS p2 ON p2.author_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

gives wrong results on the column "likePoints2" while this

```
SELECT u.username, 
SUM(p2.likes)*2 AS likePoints2 
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created >= DATE('2013-09-16') AND created <= DATE('2013-09-30')) AS p2 ON p2.author_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

is completely correct.

Problem is, I need to sum up all the posts.likes on posts.author_id = current u.id within the given date-range.

I'd appreciate any input!

**TEST-DATA**

USERS

```
id | recommendedByUserId
1  | 3
2  | 3
3  | NULL
4  | 1
```

POSTS

```
author_id | likes
1         | 5
3         | 2
4         | 1
```

So in the above example, the result should be:

```
userid | recommPoints | likePoints1 | likePoints2
1      | 10           | 1           | 10
2      | NULL         | NULL        | NULL
3      | 20           | 5           | 4
4      | NULL         | NULL        | 2
```

Comment: What wrong results are you getting?

Comment: Did you try `right outer join`s? You could also directly join the tables while using the where clause of these subqueries as additional condition for the join predicate (possible performance gain).

Comment: @GoatCO the SUM is just too high, can't tell where it comes from.

Comment: @Sam, a right outer join on which of the joins do you mean?

Comment: A left (outer) join joins zero (NULL) or one record for each record in the left table 'users'. You want to create some stats? Then, you need to involve all associated records per user, from posts and recommendedByUserId, that means, all joins shall be right outer joins.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I'd REALLY like to know the reasons for downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that each join adds multiple rows for the joined values. So you end up counting things multiple times. The general way to solve it to to make each individual grouping a separate sub select. You can leave one as part of the main select.

A good way to diagnose these sorts of problems is to remove the group by, and look at the underlying data set. Use a where clause to restrict to a known case that doesn't work.

```
Select
    u.username, 
    p1.likePoints1, 
    p1.recommPoints,
    Sum(p2.likes) * 2 As likePoints2 -- assume the *2 is part of the algorithm
From
    users u
        Left Outer Join (
            Select
                r.recommendedByUserId rid,
                Sum(p.likes) AS likePoints1,
                Count(Distinct r.id) * 10 As recommPoints
            From
                users r
                    Left Outer Join
                posts p
                    On r.id = p.author_id And 
                       p.created >= Date('2013-09-16') And
                       p.created <= Date('2013-09-30')
            Where
                r.created >= Date('2013-09-16') And 
                r.created <= Date('2013-09-30')
            Group By
                r.recommendedByUserId
    ) p1
        on u.id = p1.rid
        Left Outer Join
    posts p2
        On p2.author_id = u.id And
           p2.created >= Date('2013-09-16') And
           p2.created <= Date('2013-09-30')
Group By
    u.username,
    p1.likePoints1,
    p1.recommPoints
```

Cutdown **<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee0f6/3)</kbd>**

Comment: That looks good, but (I left that away in my question) I need the "ruid" column for "COUNT(DISTINCT ruid)*10 AS recommPoints"

Comment: I tried, but it's well beyond my capabilites in SQL I have to admit :(

Comment: got it, I think... I'm not as dump as supposed ;)... or am I... doesn't work. I just added "r.id as ruid" right below "r.recommendedByUserId rid" and "COUNT(DISTINCT ruid)*10 AS recommPoints" on top, doesn't do the job :(

Comment: ok I see what I've done wrong, I have to count inside the subselect, I'll try your version now

Comment: I think your Group By is missing a comma and after that I get a "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"... where is that coming from? Ah I see you already fixed it... let's try again!

Comment: something is still wrong, "recommPoints" is either NULL or 10 in each row now. That's not true, as some users.id are in multiple users.recommendedByUserId and should therefore get a multitude of 10...

Comment: @RaphaelJeger This would be a lot easier if you'd posted test data. I've made another edit.